# Get location using Cell-tower signal

Tags: ios, geolocation

I am making an iOS application and need to get the location of a user. I just need to get the state/province of the user and so a cell-tower signal will serve the purpose. Is there an iOS API that will allow me to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: you should probably use the [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocationManager) class for that.

Answer (score 0):

As Jake suggested Core location would be your best bet, try this for some example code  [How to find your current location with CoreLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516967/how-to-find-your-current-location-with-corelocation)

Answer (score 0):

Check out "[Getting the User's Location](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1)" in the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)