# how to avoid nulls while getting current location?

Tags: xcode, null, location, core-location, nslog

I want to get users current location and i found that solution in stackoverflow: [How to find your current location with CoreLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516967/how-to-find-your-current-location-with-corelocation).
but in spite of that solution i get that message on Nslog:
 `2013-05-07 23:57:56.962 XXXXX[1951:c07] Latitude:(null),Longitude:(null)`

Here is what i have done:

In header file:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
NSString *UsersCurrentLatitude;
NSString *UsersCurrentLongitude;
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

in implemention:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        UsersCurrentLongitude:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
        UsersCurrentLatitude:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];

            locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        NSLog(@"Latitude:%@,Longitude:%@",UsersCurrentLatitude,UsersCurrentLongitude);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a step here, you need to start the location service then get the position from the delegates. You might want to take a look at an [exemple from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html) or at this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/).